# How to import correctly with pep8 with long names

Tags: python, import, python-import, pep8

You shouldn't use lines with more than 80 chars in Python. But I'm wondering how to import long lines like e.g.

```
from .exceptions import PartsNotFitException, PartsmanagementException, CircleDetectedException
```

I was thinking of

```
from .exceptions import PartsNotFitException
from .exceptions import PartsmanagementException
from .exceptions import CircleDetectedException
```

but somehow this looks weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parentheses to allow linebreaks:

```
from .exceptions import (
    PartsNotFitException,
    PartsmanagementException,
    CircleDetectedException
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Break them into multiple lines with parentheses, it is PEP8 compliant (e.g. would pass `pep8` command)

```
from .exceptions import (
    PartsNotFitException,
    PartsmanagementException,
    CircleDetectedException,
)
```

What I like about it:

- PEP8 compliant
- With the imports on each lines, it is easy to comment/uncomment a given import.
- And with the trailing comma `,` on the last import, you can append an import at the end, without it creating a source control diff on the previous line because you don't have to add a comma on the previous line later on.